Film about a kidnapped blind woman who has the code to build a telescopic sight for a rifle
Plot: Father invents telescopic sight for a rifle, he passes a number code for production of the scope to his blind daughter before he dies. 
The daughter now a woman is kidnapped? and is being held in a painted black room, a man (a waiter, who looks like her husband) is hired by a company that wants the number code and he pretends to be her husband. 
The blind womans name is Joanna/Johanna? 
She is killed by a gunshot on some stairs at the end of the film. 
It is a foreign film, possibly French? Baroque/ Victorian setting. 
In the opening scene people are testing the telescopic sight on a rifle, a little girl with a balloon gets shot and the balloon floats away. 
I think it came out around 2012.
